# Convert AJAX callback data to Backbone model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Is there any way to convert success callback `data` to a Backbone model?
These are what I have:

```
App.Models.Image = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute : 'image_id'
});

App.Collections.Image = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model : App.Models.Image,
  url : JSON_URL,
  fetchImage : function(model) {
    var self = this;
    var imageId = model.id, name = model.get('name');

    this.fetch({
      data : {
        packet : JSON.stringify({
          type : 'loadImage',
          param : {
            image_id : imageId,
            filename : name
          }
        })
      },
      type : 'POST',
      success : function(data) {    
        var `view` = new App.Views.Image({
          model : data
        });

        view.render();
      },
      error : function() {
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Looking at success function, I declared view with callback `data` as its model.
However when the program calls the render function, the model is being displayed as `[Object]` (based on console.log) so I assume the `data` is passed as an Object, and not a backbone model.

Note:
`App.Collections.Image` is dependent to another collection. It works fine, and have nothing to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the instance of model to the view

```
 var `view` = new App.Views.Image({
   model : new App.Models.Image(data)
 });
```

Note : I am not sure what you are trying to achieve as you are fetching the collection and using response to initiate the model.